# EF Error - The property is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified .

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

Currently I am working on an application in which I am using Entity Framework code first approach.

I have a TransactionDetails class as per below

```
[Table("TransactionDetails")]
    public class TransactionDetails
    {
[DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Key]
    public int? TransactionRow { get; set; }
    public int? TransactionID { get; set; }
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public string AccountType { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public float Credit { get; set; }
    public float Debit { get; set; }
}
```

Also I am trying to insert a record into the table where the insertion code is as per below

```
setTransactionID();
            try
            {
                bankingApplicationDBContext.transactiondetails.Add(_creditTransaction);
                bankingApplicationDBContext.SaveChanges();
                bankingApplicationDBContext.transactiondetails.Add(_debitTransaction);
                bankingApplicationDBContext.SaveChanges();


            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Where _creditTransaction and _debitTransaction are two different objects of the Transaction Details class.

Also method setTransactionID() contains code as per below.

```
public void setTransactionID()
        {
            try
            {
                int TransactionID = Convert.ToInt32(bankingApplicationDBContext.transactiondetails.Max(x => x.TransactionID)) + 1;

                int TransactionRow = Convert.ToInt32(bankingApplicationDBContext.transactiondetails.Max(x => x.TransactionRow)) + 1;

                _creditTransaction.TransactionRow = TransactionRow;
                _creditTransaction.TransactionID = TransactionID;

                _debitTransaction.TransactionRow = TransactionRow + 1;
                _debitTransaction.TransactionID = TransactionID;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

Here TransactionRow and TransactionID fields I am generating as autogenerated fields and rest of the properties of objects get assigned when I enter fields into the form.

Now the problem is at the first time these objects insert the data correctly, but when the instances of the object _creditTransaction and _debitTransaction are active and I try to insert data second time, it give an error message as

The property 'TransactionRow' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: It isn't clear to me, are you assigning new instances to _creditTransaction and _debitTransaction each time? Or are you re-using the same instances for the second execution? If the latter, try creating new instances for each insertion.

Comment: when your key rows have values and you are inside the context (e.g. ChangeTracker will set the entitystate to modified), you cannot change the key information since these are concurrency tokens.

Comment: Hi Simes, Hi DevilSuichiro,

As per my analysis I have found that I was using the same instance of DBContext to save the changes into the database and was causing an issue. 

I tried creating new instance of DBContext at each insertion and the issue got resolved.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Sudhir Chavan  Totally saved my life. I was about to recreate the edmx which is a total pain. Thanks for much!